# is pybel.py broken? Using AutoDock Vina for covalent docking

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, anaconda3, openbabel

I download the adcovalent package to attempt covalent docking with AutoDock Vina, I have Anaconda, and openbabel installed. pybel.py is a wrapper for openbabel, it looks to me like pybel.py is broken, although I have the most recent version.

This is the script I'm trying to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import sys, os, math
import pybel
ob = pybel.ob
import argparse
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt, sin, cos, acos, degrees
import ResidueProfiler
from CopyMol import MoleculeDuplicator



def makePdb(coord, keyw = "ATOM  ", at_index = 1, res_index = 1, atype = 'X', elem = None,
            res = "CNT", chain  ="Z", bfactor = 10,pcharge = 0.0):
    if not elem: elem = atype
    
    bfactor = "%2.2f" % bfactor
    if len(bfactor.split(".")[0]) == 1:
        bfactor = " "+bfactor
    if len(atype) == 1:
        atype = atype + " "
    
    "%-6s%5d %4s%1s%3s %1s%4d%1s   %8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%6.2f          %2s%2s"
    atom = "%s%5d %2s   %3s %1s%4d    %8.3f%8.3f%8.3f  1.00 %s  %8.3f %1s" % (keyw,
            at_index, elem, res, chain, res_index, 
            coord[0], coord[1], coord[2], bfactor, pcharge, atype)
    return atom

def writeList(filename, inlist, mode = 'w', addNewLine = False):
    if addNewLine: nl = "\n"
    else: nl = ""
    fp = open(filename, mode)
    for i in inlist:
        fp.write(str(i)+nl)
    fp.close()


def vector(p1 , p2 = None, norm = 0): # TODO use Numpy?
    if not p2 == None:
        vec = np.array([p2[0]-p1[0],p2[1]-p1[1],p2[2]-p1[2]],'f')
    else:
        vec = np.array([p1[0], p1[1], p1[2] ], 'f' )

    if norm:
        return normalize(vec)
    else:
        return vec

def dot(vector1, vector2):  # TODO remove and use Numpy
    dot_product = 0.
    for i in range(0, len(vector1)):
        dot_product += (vector1[i] * vector2[i])
    return dot_product

def vecAngle(v1, v2, rad=1): # TODO remove and use Numpy?
    angle = dot(normalize(v1), normalize(v2))
    try:
        if rad:
            return acos(angle)
        else:
            return degrees(acos(angle))
    except:
        print "#vecAngle> CHECK TrottNormalization"
        return 0

def norm(A): # TODO use Numpy
        "Return vector norm"
        return math.sqrt(sum(A*A))

def normalize(A): # TODO use Numpy
        "Normalize the Vector"
        return A/norm(A)



def calcPlane(p1, p2, p3):
    # returns the plane containing the 3 input points
    v12 = vector(p1,p2)
    v13 = vector(p3,p2)
    return normalize(np.cross(v12, v13))



def rotatePoint(pt,m,ax):
    """
    Rotate a point applied in m around a pivot ax ?


    pt = point that is rotated
    ax = vector around which rotation is performed
    """
    # point 
    x=pt[0]
    y=pt[1]
    z=pt[2]
    # rotation pivot
    u=ax[0]
    v=ax[1]
    w=ax[2]
    ux=u*x
    uy=u*y
    uz=u*z
    vx=v*x
    vy=v*y
    vz=v*z
    wx=w*x
    wy=w*y
    wz=w*z
    sa=sin(ax[3])
    ca=cos(ax[3])
    p0 =(u*(ux+vy+wz)+(x*(v*v+w*w)-u*(vy+wz))*ca+(-wy+vz)*sa)+ m[0]
    p1=(v*(ux+vy+wz)+(y*(u*u+w*w)-v*(ux+wz))*ca+(wx-uz)*sa)+ m[1]
    p2=(w*(ux+vy+wz)+(z*(u*u+v*v)-w*(ux+vy))*ca+(-vx+uy)*sa)+ m[2]
    return np.array([ p0, p1, p2])




class CovalentDockingMaker:

    def __init__(self, 
            lig,    # ligand openbabel molecule
            rec,    # receptor openbabel molecule
            resName,# residue id to be modifled (i.e. A:THR276)

            smartsLig=None, smartsRec=None,   # use SMARTS patterns
                                              # patterns should be aligned
            smartsIdxLig=(), smartsIdxRec=(), # align using atomIdx from SMARTS patterns

            bondIdxLig=None, bondIdxRec=None, # use bonds

            indicesLig=None, indicesRec=None, # use atom indices in both

            genFullRec = False,               # add the covalent ligand to the receptor
                                              # as modified residue; this is *NOT* 
                                              # recommended, because it can lead to
                                              # spurious bonds between the mod res
                                              # and the rest of the receptor
            genLigand = False,                  


            auto=True,                        # start automatically
            debug = False,
            verbose=False):

        self.verbose = verbose
        self.debug = debug
        # LIGAND 
        dup = MoleculeDuplicator(lig)
        self.lig = dup.getCopy()
        # parameters(REQUIRED)
        self.smartsLig = smartsLig       # smarts 
        self.smartsIdxLig = smartsIdxLig # smarts indices
        self.bondIdxLig = bondIdxLig     # bonds
        self.indicesLig = indicesLig     # indices (direct)

        
        self.fullRec = rec
        self.resName = resName.upper()
        
        self.smartsRec = smartsRec        # smarts           
        self.smartsIdxRec = smartsIdxRec  # smarts indices
        self.bondIdxRec = bondIdxRec      # bonds
        self.indicesRec = indicesRec      # indices (direct)
        
        self.genFullRec = genFullRec
        self.setMode()
        self.initResidue() 
        if auto:
            self.process()


    def vprint(self, msg):
        
        if not self.verbose:
            return
        print("VERBOSE " + msg)
    

    def setMode(self):  

        if self.indicesLig:
            self._ligmode = 'idx'
        elif self.smartsLig:
            self._ligmode = 'smarts'
        elif self.bondIdxLig:
            self._ligmode = 'bond'
        self.vprint("[setMode] ligand alignment mode: %s" % self._ligmode)
       
        if self.indicesRec:
            self._recmode = 'idx'
        elif self.smartsRec:
            self._recmode = 'smarts'
        elif self.bondIdxRec:
            self._recmode = 'bond'
        else:
            self._recmode = 'smarts'
            self.vprint("[setMode] no mode specified-> switching to default")
        self.vprint("[setMode] receptor alignment mode: %s" % self._recmode)
    
    def initResidue(self):
       
        string = self.resName
        chain, res = string.split(":")
        self.resInfo = { 'chain' : chain,
                         'name'  : res[0:3],
                         'num': int(res[3:]),
                       }
        if self.debug: print "PROCESSING RESIDUE", self.resName
        self.residueProfile()

    def process(self):
        
        if self.verbose: print "Aligning ligand on residue...", self.resName
        self.align()
        self.cleanup()

    def residueProfile(self):

        self.receptorProfiler = ResidueProfiler.AminoAcidProfiler(self.fullRec,
                resId=self.resName, setLabels=True, 
                auto=True, debug=self.debug)
        self.resType = self.receptorProfiler.residues[self.resName]['type']
        if self.verbose: 
            print "Selected residue recognized as:", self.resType.upper()
        dup = MoleculeDuplicator(self.fullRec, resList=[self.resName]) 
        self.modifiedRes = dup.getCopy()
        if self._recmode == 'idx':
            org = self.indicesRec[:]
            self.indicesRec = [ self.modifiedRes._numbering[x] for x in self.indicesRec]
            self.vprint( ('converting full receptor indices [%s] to '
                 'residue copy indices [%s]' % (org, self.indicesRec)))
###BLAH, BLAH... it goes on...
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
(vina) gorrie06@DMGLaptop:~/docking/covalent$ ptor /3upo_test/3upo_protein.pdb --residue B:SER222 --outputfile ligcov.pdb
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gorrie06/docking/covalent/adcovalent/prepareCovalent.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pybel
  File "/home/gorrie06/anaconda3/envs/vina/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybel.py", line 89, in <module>
    informats = _formatstodict(_obconv.GetSupportedInputFormat())
  File "/home/gorrie06/anaconda3/envs/vina/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybel.py", line 68, in _formatstodict
    broken = [(x, y.strip()) for x, y in broken]
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

This is the function in pybel that is broken:

```
def _formatstodict(list):
    if sys.platform[:4] == "java":
        list = [list.get(i) for i in range(list.size())]
    broken = [x.replace("[Read-only]", "").replace("[Write-only]", "").split(
              " -- ") for x in list]
    broken = [(x, y.strip()) for x, y in broken]
    return dict(broken)
```

It comes from an openbabel wrapper, pybel:

```
# -*. coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Noel O'Boyle; 2012, Adrià Cereto-Massagué
# All rights reserved.
#
# This file is part of Cinfony.
# The contents are covered by the terms of the GPL v2 license
# which is included in the file LICENSE_GPLv2.txt.

"""
pybel - A Cinfony module for accessing Open Babel

Global variables:
  ob - the underlying SWIG bindings for Open Babel
  informats - a dictionary of supported input formats
  outformats - a dictionary of supported output formats
  descs - a list of supported descriptors
  fps - a list of supported fingerprint types
  forcefields - a list of supported forcefields
"""

import sys
import os.path
import tempfile
import json
import uuid
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

if sys.platform[:4] == "java":
    import org.openbabel as ob
    import java.lang.System
    java.lang.System.loadLibrary("openbabel_java")
    _obfuncs = ob.openbabel_java
    _obconsts = ob.openbabel_javaConstants
    import javax
elif sys.platform[:3] == "cli":
    import System
    import clr
    clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
    clr.AddReference('System.Drawing')

    from System.Windows.Forms import Application, DockStyle, Form, PictureBox
    from System.Windows.Forms import PictureBoxSizeMode
    from System.Drawing import Image, Size

    _obdotnet = os.environ["OBDOTNET"]
    if _obdotnet[0] == '"':  # Remove trailing quotes
        _obdotnet = _obdotnet[1:-1]
    clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(os.path.join(_obdotnet, "OBDotNet.dll"))
    import OpenBabel as ob
    _obfuncs = ob.openbabel_csharp
    _obconsts = ob.openbabel_csharp
else:
    import openbabel as ob
    _obfuncs = _obconsts = ob
    try:
        import Tkinter as tk
        import Image as PIL
        import ImageTk as piltk
    except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
        tk = None


def _formatstodict(list):
    if sys.platform[:4] == "java":
        list = [list.get(i) for i in range(list.size())]
    broken = [x.replace("[Read-only]", "").replace("[Write-only]", "").split(
              " -- ") for x in list]
    broken = [(x, y.strip()) for x, y in broken]
    return dict(broken)


def _getplugins(findplugin, names):
    return dict([(x, findplugin(x)) for x in names if findplugin(x)])


def _getpluginnames(ptype):
    if sys.platform[:4] == "cli":
        plugins = ob.VectorString()
    else:
        plugins = ob.vectorString()
    ob.OBPlugin.ListAsVector(ptype, None, plugins)
    if sys.platform[:4] == "java":
        plugins = [plugins.get(i) for i in range(plugins.size())]
    return [x.split()[0] for x in plugins]

_obconv = ob.OBConversion()
_builder = ob.OBBuilder()

informats = _formatstodict(_obconv.GetSupportedInputFormat())
"""A dictionary of supported input formats"""
outformats = _formatstodict(_obconv.GetSupportedOutputFormat())
"""A dictionary of supported output formats"""

descs = _getpluginnames("descriptors")
"""A list of supported descriptors"""
_descdict = _getplugins(ob.OBDescriptor.FindType, descs)

fps = [_x.lower() for _x in _getpluginnames("fingerprints")]
"""A list of supported fingerprint types"""
_fingerprinters = _getplugins(ob.OBFingerprint.FindFingerprint, fps)

forcefields = [_x.lower() for _x in _getpluginnames("forcefields")]
"""A list of supported forcefields"""
_forcefields = _getplugins(ob.OBForceField.FindType, forcefields)

charges = [_x.lower() for _x in _getpluginnames("charges")]
"""A list of supported charge models"""
_charges = _getplugins(ob.OBChargeModel.FindType, charges)

operations = _getpluginnames("ops")
"""A list of supported operations"""
_operations = _getplugins(ob.OBOp.FindType, operations)

ipython_3d = False
"""Toggles 2D vs 3D molecule representations in IPython notebook"""


def readfile(format, filename, opt=None):
    """Iterate over the molecules in a file.

    Required parameters:
       format - see the informats variable for a list of available
                input formats
       filename

    Optional parameters:
       opt    - a dictionary of format-specific options
                For format options with no parameters, specify the
                value as None.

    You can access the first molecule in a file using the next() method
    of the iterator (or the next() keyword in Python 3):
        mol = readfile("smi", "myfile.smi").next() # Python 2
        mol = next(readfile("smi", "myfile.smi"))  # Python 3

    You can make a list of the molecules in a file using:
        mols = list(readfile("smi", "myfile.smi"))

    You can iterate over the molecules in a file as shown in the
    following code snippet:
    >>> atomtotal = 0
    >>> for mol in readfile("sdf", "head.sdf"):
    ...     atomtotal += len(mol.atoms)
    ...
    >>> print atomtotal
    43
    """
    if opt is None:
        opt = {}
    obconversion = ob.OBConversion()
    formatok = obconversion.SetInFormat(format)
    for k, v in opt.items():
        if v is None:
            obconversion.AddOption(k, obconversion.INOPTIONS)
        else:
            obconversion.AddOption(k, obconversion.INOPTIONS, str(v))
    if not formatok:
        raise ValueError("%s is not a recognised Open Babel format" % format)
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise IOError("No such file: '%s'" % filename)

    def filereader():
        obmol = ob.OBMol()
        notatend = obconversion.ReadFile(obmol, filename)
        while notatend:
            yield Molecule(obmol)
            obmol = ob.OBMol()
            notatend = obconversion.Read(obmol)
    return filereader()


def readstring(format, string, opt=None):
    """Read in a molecule from a string.

    Required parameters:
       format - see the informats variable for a list of available
                input formats
       string

    Optional parameters:
       opt    - a dictionary of format-specific options
                For format options with no parameters, specify the
                value as None.

    Example:
    >>> input = "C1=CC=CS1"
    >>> mymol = readstring("smi", input)
    >>> len(mymol.atoms)
    5
    """
    if opt is None:
        opt = {}

    obmol = ob.OBMol()
    obconversion = ob.OBConversion()
###it goes on from here...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you!